# Fortify Fix High : Cross-Site Scripting Reflected

Tags: xss, fortify

```
this.lbHint.Text += dt.Rows[i]["HINT_NAME"].ToString() + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
```

Fortify scan this line as XSS reflected. I try to use `Server.HtmlEncode()` to `this.lbHint.Text += Server.HtmlEncode(dt.Rows[i]["HINT_NAME"].ToString()) + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";`, but it seems doesn't work. Fortify still scan it.

---

```
this.labQueryHeader.Text += "<br />";
```

And there is the same question(XSS reflected). How do I fix it and pass Fortify scan?

Thanks for your help: )

Comment: It is on the latest .NET framework ? or a very old ?

Comment: Hi, SPoint it's on .NET framework 3.5

Comment: Consider to add some modification to the web.config as the ASP.NET 3.5 did not do this cleanly. Add this : <httpRuntime encoderType="Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXssEncoder, AntiXssLibrary" />